# D3 + canvas - inconsistent stroke width

Tags: d3.js, html5-canvas, linechart

I recently switched from SVG to canvas in my D3 line chart for performance reasons. However, I am encountering an issue when drawing the line:

[image: Graph demonstration]

As you can see, the vertical lines are much thicker than the horizontal lines, which is an ugly effect. My context settings are the following:

```js
context.beginPath();
line(data.map(message => message.payload));
context.fill();
context.lineWidth = 2.5;
context.strokeStyle = "steelblue";
context.stroke();
```

Is there a way to avoid this issue?

Comment: How are you creating the canvas? Does it start out square and then get transformed to be wider?

Comment: @BallpointBen Whoops - I realized I had been using the wrong factor for scaling, so it was in fact mistakenly generating a square image and scaling it. I updated to the correct variable and the problem was solved. Thanks!